# How can I calculate the percent of change vs prior period off the total row in an SSRS Matrix?

Tags: reporting-services

Have an SSRS Matrix that I am trying to calculate the percent of change vs prior period off the total row.

Have tried using the previous function based on my understanding of it but either I am doing it wrong or that is not the correct method to generate the results that I need.